# Why is low resistance beneficial to ion exchange membranes?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, graphene

http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jcp/139/11/10.1063/1.4821161

The article states that the graphene filter has a much lower electrical resistance than existing ion exchange membranes, giving the graphene an advantage. Why is having a low electrical resistance beneficial to ion exchange membranes?

Answer (score 0):

Ion-exchange membranes used in electrodialysis are used to separate a saline solution into a low concentration diluate and high concentration concentrate. The voltage that this salinity gradient generates needs to be overcome by an external power source, and the continual flow of inflowing water means that you consistently supply the electrodialysis apparatus with electric current. The lower the resistance of the ion-exchange membranes, the lower the power requirement is for supplying the required electric current.